# Bitmap saving corrupted image

Tags: java, android, android-camera

While saving an image from the camera to an external storage directory, the image appears as a grey box in the gallery and is not visible in the file manager as well.
I have already enabled the required write permissions for the storage as well.

The image looks like this in the gallery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m55AL.jpg

```
String filepath= "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Email_Client/1564907913797.jpg"
File file = new File(filepath);
file.createNewFile();
final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fos);
fos.close();
```

Comment: How do you get the **bitmap**?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
String filepath= "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Email_Client/1564907913797.jpeg"
File file = new File(filepath);
file.createNewFile();
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
OutputStream outstream;
try {
  outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageUri);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outstream);
  outstream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Camera (and not Camera2) and PictureCallback, try this:

```
String filepath= "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Email_Client/1564907913797.jpg"
File file = new File(filepath);
final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(data);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fos);
fos.close();
```

where `data` is the array of bytes of the picture taken by the camera that you get as parameter in `onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)`.
The files you save are empty because you're not actually saving any picture data.